# Unable to install python packager in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a newbie here. I'm facing problem in installing the packager Pillow (PYTHON) in PYCHRAM. need help or suggestion to help me solve problem.

[need to install package PIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqF8E.jpg)

Comment: We need more information as to what the problem is. What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure it is Phyton and not Python? (OCD is going crazy)

Comment: If you are using Python 3.8, the problem is described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823496/how-to-fix-pip-installation-error-on-pillow). Please state the Python version and OS you are using.