# Why I can't install pillow with pip

Tags: python, django, pip

I created a ImageField in model.py file and when I tried to run Python gave me an error. It says I have to install pillow . So I typed pip install pillow command.
Then it started installing and after some time (though I thought it was successfully installed) it gave another error and said that it was not successfully installed. It gave me bunch of red colored text that I didn't understand.

Comment: can you share what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Consider posting the errors because it provides information on why it did not successfully install. Also, it might help if you provide what OS you are using.

Comment: Also, have a check if this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823496/how-to-fix-pip-installation-error-on-pillow solves your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it works.

```
pip install pillow
```

To check the version or whether it is installed type the following command.

```
import PIL
print('PIL',PIL.__version__)
```

> Output (for my machine)

```
PIL 6.2.0
```

You can also install Pillow along with pip by the following command.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

I hope it would be helpful.